# How to extract common props with vue3 in SFC `<script setup>`

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-sfc

Sometimes we can extract common props using `props` in `defineComponent` function as below. Both works in vue2/vue3 but not in SFC.

```js
// common-props.js
export default {
  commonProps: {
    enabled: Boolean,
    readonly: Boolean,
  }
}

// my-component.vue
import { commonProps } from './common-props';

export default {
  props: {
    ...commonProps,
    visible: Boolean,
    text: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    }
  }
};
```

But when I upgrade to `<script setup>`. The `props` is defined by `defineProps` which is a compiler macro. I have to try to use typescript extended the props as follow. But the mixined props is not visible from DevTools.

```js
// common-props.ts
export interface CommonProps{
  enabled?: boolean,
  readonly?: boolean,
}

//  my-component.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import CommonProps from './common-props';

interface MyComponentProps extends CommonProps {
  visible?: boolean,
  text?: string,
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<ICheckBoxProps>(), {
  visible: false,
  text: '',
});

</script>
```

My question is how to extract props from SFC components. And make the Vue Devtools can recognize the extracted props.

Answer (score 2):

[Type-only props/emit declarations](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features)

> As of now, the type declaration argument must be one of the following
> to ensure correct static analysis:
>
> 1. A type literal
> 2. A reference to an interface or a type literal in the same file
>
> Currently complex types and type imports from other files are not
> supported. It is theoretically possible to support type imports in the
> future

So short answer is no, it is currently not possible to use imported types when using [Type-only props declaration](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#type-only-props-emit-declarations)

But you can still use non-type (object based) prop declaration inside `script setup`

```js
// CommonProps.js
export default {
    enabled: Boolean,
    readonly: Boolean,
}
```

```js
// Component.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import {ref} from "vue";
import CommonProps from "./CommonProps.js"
  
const props = defineProps({
  ...CommonProps,
  items: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => []
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <pre>{{ props }}</pre>
</template>
```

[Demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: is there a way to get the type of common props like `type commonProps={enabled:boolean,readonly:boolean}`, I mean a normal TS type or interface ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim just figured out I can `ExtractPropTypes<typeof myComponentProps>` using `import { ExtractPropTypes } from '@vue/runtime-core'`