# Vue3 using Interface as Prop Types

Tags: vuejs3, typescript-typings, nuxtjs3

I am having an issue using an Interface as a Vue3 Prop, the goal is to use the interface as a type check on the prop: (We are using Nuxt3 so alot of the imports are not listed below)

```
// IsProduct.ts

export interface IsProduct {
  _id: string;
  productName: string;
  icon: string
}
```

```
// ProductDisplay.vue

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { IsProduct } from "./IsProduct";

interface Props {
  product: IsProduct | string | null;
}
const {
  product = null,
} = defineProps<Props>();

let productObj: IsProduct = ref(null);
let productRef: string = ref(null);
let displayText: string = ref("");

watch(
  () => product,
  () => {
    initialize();
  },
  { immediate: true }
);

function initialize() {
  productRef = null;
  productObj = null;
  if (!product) return;
  if (typeof product === "object") {
    productRef = product._id;
    productObj = product;
  }
  if (typeof product === "string") {
    productRef = product;
    productObj = productByRef[product]; //<-- productByRef goes to Pinia store
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <span>
    <span v-if="productObj">{{productObj.productName}} <fa-icon :icon="productObj.icon"></span>
  </span>
</template>
```

```
// ProductList.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
const { products } = useProductStore() // <-- list of products from Pinia store
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <-- THIS WORKS because the _id is a string, no Vue warnings -->
    <ProductDisplay :product="p._id" v-for="p of products" :key="p._id" />

    <-- HAS VUE WARNINGS because the p is the full Object-->
    <ProductDisplay :product="p" v-for="p of products" :key="p._id" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Is there a way to have Vue understand that when a full Object is passed in that it uses the IsProduct interface?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70061154/381282

Comment: Thanks @MichalLevý, the VueJS [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features) regarding TS under <script setup>. this sentence making the point clear:

"If the type is a reference to an imported type, the inferred result will be foo: null (equal to any type) since the compiler does not have information of external files."

Comment: There is work on a Vite [plugin](https://github.com/wheatjs/vite-plugin-vue-type-imports) to add Type support to defineProps.  However you need to define the entire set of props to the component as one interface, not as one individual prop as in the example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a 'work around' for the example that I posted above:

```
// IsProduct.ts

export interface IsProduct {
  _id: string;
  productName: string;
  icon: string
}
```

```
// ProductDisplay.vue

<script lang="ts" setup>
...
interface Props {
  product: {_id: string} | string | null; <-- Change the Interface to an Object
}
...

function initialize() {
  productRef = null;
  productObj = null;
  if (!product) return;
  if (typeof product === "object") {
    productRef = product._id;
    productObj = product as IsProduct; <-- cast the product prop as IsProduct
  }
}
...
</script>
```

Since the ProductDisplay.vue component is looking for either a Product Object or the string _id of a Product, in the Props I just defined an Object with _id of string since that is required.  This tells the Vue compiler, 'hey this is either an object or a string' and there are no warnings in the devtools console.

Later in the code I check if this is an Object and if so, then cast the Object to the 'type of' IsProduct.  This removes the Typescript warnings in VSCode.